# Android Web View

Tags: android, view, webview

I am curious if there is a way from within a WebView when a button is clicked it display a new view on top of the current display.

I have a web site and when the user clicks the signature field I want to be able to capture the signature on the device. From the best I can tell the easiest way is to write this section in the Android SDK. I'm trying to avoid rewriting the entire website.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [addJavaScript interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).  Looks like you can call a javaobject via javascript.  So you could put some javascript behind a button onclick handler that could call some java that would display a dialog with the second webview.

Comment: thanks, I discovered this approach the other day and meant to update the question with how I approached the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could create an intent that your activity with the webview responds to.
This is easier than you'd think:

For a recent Twitter implementation, there was a callback from twitter so that the browser navigates to myapp:myintent. In the android manifest, you declare an activity handles myapp:intent. When that url is navigated to, it launches your activity via the OnNewIntent event in which you can show your new view on top.

Hope this helps.